# Correct use of const c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have this sample code ( below ), example1() method works with no problem, example2() is similar but I must force const_char to make it compile, although I consider as example1() method is not needed, example2() would be not needed either.

My question is, how can I modify add() method to make both compile or how must I correctly call buffer.add() in example2() without forcing const_cast? add() method is not modifying item, so const_cast is unnecessary. Which is the correct or suitable form?

Here's the sample code:

```
template <class Item>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Item *      _pItems;
    int         _nItems;
    // ... constructor / destructors etc
    void    add( const Item & item ) // or maybe Item const & item
    {
        _pItems[_nItems++] = item;
    }
};
class MyClass
{
public:
    // data
};
void    example1( const MyClass & item )
{
    Buffer<MyClass>        buffer;
    buffer.add( item );  // WORKS, no problem
}
void    example2( const MyClass & item )
{
    Buffer<MyClass *>        buffer; // NOW with pointers to MyClass
    //buffer.add( item );  // ERROR: 'Buffer<Item>::add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass *const &'
    buffer.add( const_cast<MyClass *>( &item ) );  // forcing const_cast WORKS
}
```

Comment: `// forcing const_cast WORKS` Yea, but now your compiler won't prevent you from modifying the object, which is _still UB_. It's a crude hack that causes problems; it does not solve them. (Sometimes you do need this hack to pass to old C functions that have only a written-in-comments mutability contract, not `const`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like :

```
Buffer<MyClass const*>
```

because &item on a const MyClass is a Myclass const* not a MyClass*

Comment: And as a corollary, if you can't do that because some other part of your code is relying on the buffer containing non-const `MyClass *`s, then you're doing something wrong by adding a const one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Buffer` class template can be considered to be correct and it is your `example2` function which is incorrect.  I'll proceed on that basis.

In `example1`, the function has a const reference parameter to an instance of a `MyClass`.  The `add` method of `Buffer` then makes a copy of the value of the instance, placing it in its own memory buffer (I hope `Buffer` is keeping track of all of this memory).  Therefore the fact that `example` takes a const reference is irrelevant to `Buffer` since a copy of the value is made.

In `example2`, the `add` method of `Buffer` is taking a copy of the pointer to the instance of `MyClass` and storing that in its own memory buffer.  In `example2` you have instantiated `Buffer` as holding non-const pointers to `MyClass`, so that is what you should be giving it, so `example2` should be:

```
void example2( MyClass & item )
{
    Buffer<MyClass *> buffer; // NOW with pointers to MyClass
    buffer.add( &item );
}
```

Now, you must be aware that if `buffer` were to be used, the `item` must remain fixed in memory until you've finished with it.  Whereas in `example1`, the items can go away since you've safely stored copies in `buffer`.